# Recovering png (sort of forensic)

Tags: security, png, decode, computer-forensics

I am trying to decode a png which is slightly corrupt. The sublime text shows correct header, etc. I found this tool online pngcsum : which gives the following output. Any ideas on what I could be looking at to correct this png?

./pngcsum image.07b7e81e114b85c7866cf8ce3c98409b output.png

```html
./pngcsum image.07b7e81e114b85c7866cf8ce3c98409b output.png
IHDR ( 13 ) - csum = 5873e4ea
sRGB (  1 ) - csum = aece1ce9
iTXt (1347 ) - csum = cbf5c06c
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = 02b643e7
STJF (16384 ) - csum = 321cb0f5 -> 291f0ad4
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = fb32fa8c
IXXR (16384 ) - csum = 4d0b77bc -> 40e5ee41
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = ca855b6c
SQRE (16384 ) - csum = c42a71f3 -> adf6d151
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = c680d5da
JPTV (16384 ) - csum = df0be1b2 -> 3a8455ed
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = 4b0ab80e
OLCD (16384 ) - csum = 8d80236e -> dfcabe31
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = 9ed6a137
QRMY (16384 ) - csum = dd70cf8f -> a7a32e44
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = 9454f835
BKIU (16384 ) - csum = 33b58e4f -> ebde8d51
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = 53be3fd8
PRYI (16384 ) - csum = 746199d5 -> da6943d3
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = 54fd18ac
MPHP (16384 ) - csum = cfcfcd8c -> 519da2f5
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = 9d113786
IRRV (16384 ) - csum = 61e635cf -> 3d5ba4fc
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = b088f485
JZGL (16384 ) - csum = a7b3ab6f -> 96f1ff1b
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = 581c91e9
OMIK (16384 ) - csum = 19710b80 -> 3d968efd
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = e25b5ec7
PFUH (16384 ) - csum = 4a44bb91 -> 0d47742e
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = 162bd188
YTWT (16384 ) - csum = bc255b19 -> 2f3f9bca
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = 763b826a
BGIW (16384 ) - csum = e7448399 -> d6ffc483
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = 0dd20979
ARDA (16384 ) - csum = 881a30a9 -> f41f9401
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = f14d1cf7
KMTS (16384 ) - csum = 102e014f -> 0a24e0c1
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = 0c02dbc3
LIBJ (16384 ) - csum = 70dd0979 -> ebbd58d9
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = a6564465
ETYV (16384 ) - csum = 3b37fd04 -> ba4668c7
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = 0c38be75
DQMF (16384 ) - csum = ac99a5b5 -> c14d9816
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = 9086d878
PWMJ (16384 ) - csum = 226fdd4f -> ad0a79f3
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = a0524834
DGOC (16384 ) - csum = 6d589275 -> 550e40c1
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = c80e2865
RTPV (16384 ) - csum = a7098ad0 -> 78bc0011
IDAT (16384 ) - csum = 738c37d8
LNMS (6215 ) - csum = c55c86cf -> 0a7c99b5
IEND (  0 ) - csum = ae426082
```

Comment: why a "-1" and that too without explanation? You can ask me / tell me if there's something I can do to make this clear.

Comment: It looks like every other checksum is wrong - dunno why though.

Comment: Try opening in IrfanView. I'd be curious if it can render the image or not.

Comment: Try running `pngcheck` on it.